# Значення слова "постоличком"

Tags: значення-слів

СОРОКА-ДОВБУХА

> Сорока-довбуха
>   На припічку сиділа,
>   Діткам кашку варила,
>   Ополончиком мішала,
>   ***Постоличком*** накривала,
>   Усім діточкам давала:
>   Цьому дала, цьому дала,
>   Цьому дала, цьому дала,
>   Цей ще мал, круп не драв,
>   Води не носив, діжі не місив,
>   Хати не топив.
>   Пішов малий по водицю
>   Та й зустрів молодицю.
>   Молодиця не моя,
>   Молодиця Хомина
>   По бережку ходила,
>   Лебедушок гонила:
>   Шуги, шуги, шуги!

В СУМ-11 є стаття

> [Постолик](http://sum.in.ua/s/postolyk) див. постолики.
>
> [Постолики](http://sum.in.ua/s/postolyky) ків, мн. (одн. постолик, а, чол.), заст. Зменш.-пестл.
>   до постоли.
>
> [Постоли](http://sum.in.ua/s/postoly) . заст. М'яке селянське взуття з цілого шматка шкіри без
>   пришивної підошви, яке звичайно носили з онучами, прив'язуючи до ніг
>   мотузками (волоками).

Проте всі ці визначення не зовсім підходять під контекст віршика. Яке може бути значення слова ***"постоличком"***?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, [постол](http://sum.in.ua/s/postoly) (у Грінченка також [постіл](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/46059-postil.html#show_point)) тут уживається в прямому значенні — накрила кашу чоботом. Тому що, припускаю, у давніші часи, коли люди жили значно простіше й не мали мікрохвильовку, 5 видів каструль, 10 запасних рушників тощо, всі предмети побуту йшли в хід у різних призначеннях.

Є ще [«Ласочка, де ти була?»](//uk.wikisource.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0,_%D0%B4%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0%3F):

> — Ласочка, де ти була?
>   — В бога.
>   — Що ти робила?
>   — Кросенце ткала.
>   — Що ти заткала?
>   — Кусок сала.
>   — Де ти діла?
>   — Під столом.
>   **— Чим накрила?**
>   **— Постолом.**
>   — Де теє сало?
>   — Кішечка вкрала.
>   — Де тая кішечка?
>   — Побігла під піч.
>   — Де тая піч?
>   — Вода затопила.
>   — Де тая вода?
>   — Воли попили.
>   — Де тії воли?
>   — Довбні побили.
>   — Де тії довбні?
>   — Черви поточили.
>   — Де тії черви?
>   — Кури поклювали.
>   — Де тії кури?
>   — Коршаки похапали.
>   — Де тії коршаки?
>   — Полетіли на море.
>   — Де теє море?
>   — Красками заросло.
>   — Де тії краски?
>   — Порвали Параски.
>   — Де тії Параски?
>   — Вийшли заміж.
>   — За кого?
>   — За паничів.
>   — Де тії паничі?
>   — Поїхали на війну.

Згадується традиція росіян використовувати чобіт при розпалюванні самовара. Також слід зазначити, що постол (постіл) — це взуття без подошви, фактично, як я розумію, шматок шкіри. Можливо, постолами також називали подібні шматки шкіри, що не призначалися для взування або ж призначення яких ще не визначене.